# Call procedure inside procedure with multiple variables mysql

Tags: mysql, procedure

I have written a long MySQK query which I want to reuse in another query. I struggle with the part of connecting the variables from the first procedure within the second.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc1(lat double,lon double) BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Locations where latitude=lat AND longitude=lon;
END;
```

which returns an id and name

```
CREATE PROCEDURE call_procedure(lat double,lon double)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Weather WHERE procId=call proc1(lat,lon);
END;
```

What step am i missing to get the id value on the place of the call proc1(lat,lon). I tried to declare a variable but i failed.

UPDATE:
I tried to edit my code according to @Akina

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nearest_weather_station16(IN lat double,IN lon double, OUT station INT, OUT station_name VARCHAR(30), OUT distance DOUBLE)
BEGIN
   Select WeatherStations.weatherStationIndex INTO station, WeatherStations.stationName INTO station_name, (6371 * acos(cos(radians(lat)) * 
   cos(radians(Locations.latitude)) * 
   cos(radians(Locations.longitude) - 
   radians(lon)) + 
   sin(radians(lat)) * 
   sin(radians(Locations.latitude)))) as dis INTO distance
        FROM 
        (
        SELECT weatherStationIndex,weatherIndex, MAX(TIME) AS LASTSEEN
        FROM Weather where time>DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(),INTERVAL 1 hour)
        GROUP BY weatherStationIndex
        ) latest
        JOIN WeatherStations ON latest.weatherStationIndex=WeatherStations.weatherStationIndex JOIN Locations on WeatherStations.locationIndex=Locations.locationIndex
        ORDER BY dis ASC LIMIT 1;
END;
```

The code worked fine before adding the word IN and the OUT including variables and INTO including variables. Now it gives the error undeclared variable: WeatherStations

Comment: *I tried to edit my code according to @Akina* When I suggested a solution, I never said that it should be implemented with a bunch of syntax errors.See [SELECT ... INTO Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html) - only one INTO clause with the CSV list of variables is used.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE slave (IN lat double, IN lon double, OUT var_procId BIGINT)
BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO var_procId FROM Locations WHERE latitude=lat AND longitude=lon LIMIT 1;
END;
```

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE parent(lat double,lon double)
BEGIN
    DECLARE var_procId BIGINT;
    CALL slave(lat, lon, var_procId )
    SELECT * FROM Weather WHERE procId=var_procId ;
END;
```

Comment: I tried this solutions with multiple outputs, but somehow it did not recognise the original variables any more. See code above. Do you know why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

You should have implemented `proc1` as a `FUNCTION`, because you are interested in the id and the coordinate is uniquely specifying a location:

```
CREATE FUNCTION proc1(lat double,lon double) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE result INT DEFAULT NULL;
    SELECT id into result FROM Locations where latitude=lat AND longitude=lon;
    RETURN result;
END;
```

and use it like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE call_procedure(lat double,lon double)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Weather WHERE procId=proc1(lat,lon);
END;
```

Or, if you can have duplicate data, then you can use a cursor, but don't do that in this case.

Comment: `result` variable is excess - you may return query result immediately (returning datatype is scalar - so `LIMIT 1` is close to compulsory). And when the first realized then `BEGIN .. END` block become excess and may be removed.

Comment: @Akina limit 1 resolves possible duplicates. I assumed in my answer that a location is uniquely determined by the coordinates. If this assumption is false in the op's database, then LIMIT 1 is needed. I have also specified what can be done if duplicates can happen.